# wix create a backup on install to restore on uninstall

Tags: c++, wix, custom-action

I have an add-in that delivering as a part of another product. There is no installer for that add-in at all. I want create an installer that on installation, copy dlls(old dlls) of that add-in  to some directory as a backup, and install updated add-in (new dlls). On uninstallation I want to restore old dlls, e.g. replace new dlls by old dlls.

Does wix has some standard functionality to support described behavior, or custom actions?
Also, is it possible to write custom action on C++?

Answer (score 0):

1. AFAIK wix does not have anything specific to support this "backup" scenario. The whole thing may be more complicated than it seems. Imagine you have not two, but three subsequent versions of your add-in. First installed by the "big product", then updated to second, then updated to the third. What should be "restored" in case you uninstall your add-in? Should the third version do the backup when there is already one created by the second? This sort of questions.
2. Yes, you can write custom actions in C++. Before .NET Wix framework was created, that actually was the only way to build custom actions. Wix SDK includes a template project for Visual Studio to build a custom action in C++.

Comment: 1. No I don't need to worry about subsequent versions of the add-in. This is for internal use. Before installing the new version of add-in, the old one (if it wasn't uninstalled), should be uninstalled first and installer will be delivered with such instructions.